# Shortcuts and programs don’t work; switched to be associated with “Media Center.”

Tags: windows-7, windows, shortcuts

I have a problem with my programs and shortcuts. Look at this picture

[image]

Some of my programs' icon turned to media center file association and when I want to open programs, media center will be open

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your shortcut file extension association has been corrupted ('.lnk' files). You can fix this by following the instructions here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/172053

In summary:

> 1. Start Registry Editor (Regedt32.exe), select the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT subkey, and then click Add Key on the Edit menu.
> 2. In the Key Name box type ".lnk" (without quotation marks), and then click OK. Note that you should leave the Class box blank.
> 3. In the Add Value dialog box, click OK to leave the Value Name blank, and click REG_SZ in the Data Type list.
> 4. In the String Editor box, type "lnkfile" (without quotation marks), and then click OK.
> 5. Select the .lnk key you just re-created under the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT subkey. On the Edit menu, click Add Key and then type "ShellNew"
>      (without quotation marks). Note that you should leave the Class box
>      blank.
> 6. Click Add Value on the Edit menu, type "command" (without quotation marks) in the Data Name box, click REG_SZ in the Data name box, and
>      then type "RunDLL32 AppWiz.Cpl,NewLinkHere %1" (without quotation
>      marks) as the string value. Quit Registry Editor, and then restart the
>      computer.

**Important**

While not always the case, corrupted file extensions are usually caused by malware of some sort. I highly recommend you scan your computer for viruses (using AVG Free, Avast, or similar) and malware (Malwarebytes Anti-Malware, Spybot - Search & Destroy, etc.) as soon as you fix the file associations.

Comment: Thank you Dan but I can't open registry too

Comment: Why not? Press Win + R to open run prompt and type `rededt32.exe`.

Comment: I know that but my registry is as like as others..... I can't open it too

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.. Did you get some sort of malware that corrupted your `.exe` extension association as well? If so, try these instructions: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2688326

Comment: You could also try running [FixExec](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/fixexec/), (there are three versions: .com .pif and .src, try them all and see which one works).

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing) and quote cited material. I've fixed your post this time.

Comment: If you boot into WinRE you can load the HIVE for the system and resolve it manually.

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm more concerned with fixing the user's problem than perfect formatting. I posted a link to the source clearly stating where I found the information. Nevertheless, thanks for the edit.